# i am able to cout but not return why? please suggest changes

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q45ia.png)I am able to cout `A->val` but not able to return `A->val`. Why? As we can go only once inside for loop and it should return it. Please explain what is logicaly wrong in returning like this. Also suggest any changes. Thanks for helping.

```
/**

* Definition for a binary tree node.

* struct TreeNode {

*     int val;

*     TreeNode *left;

*     TreeNode *right;

*     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

*     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

*     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left),
right(right) {}

* };

*/

class Solution {
 public:
  int kthSmallest(TreeNode* A, int B) {
    if (A == NULL)

    {
      return -1;
    }

    int res;

    int k = B;

    static int i = 0;

    if (A != NULL)

    {
      kthSmallest(A->left, B);

      i++;

      if (i == k)

      {
        int res = A->val;

        cout << A->val;

        return res;
      }

      kthSmallest(A->right, B);
    }

    return -111;
  }
};
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C `NULL`.

Comment: What do you mean you can't return `A->val`?  What happens?

Comment: It's a recursive function. If it returns a value it can't call itself again. You could store all values in a vector.

Comment: i want to stop the recursion at that point. i am able to cout the value but return is  dosent do anything

Comment: i have added the result if you want to see

Comment: you call your function recursively but ignore its return value. it returns an important value right? think what you need to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, with function override to initialise `num` to `0`?:

```
const TreeNode *kthSmallest(const TreeNode *A, const int k, int &num) {
    if (!A) return nullptr;

    const TreeNode *left = kthSmallest(A->left, k, num);
    if (left != nullptr) return left;

    num++;
    if (k == num) return A;

    return kthSmallest(A->right, k, num);
}

const TreeNode *kthSmallest(const TreeNode *A, const int k) {
    int num{};
    return kthSmallest(A, k, num);
}
```